# Span text not changing

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have to change title of my popup.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
  <span id="ui-dialog-title-detailsPopup_109" class="ui-dialog-title">
    Customer : XYX
  </span>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setPopupTitle();
});

function setPopupTitle() {
  $('#ui-dialog-title-detailsPopup_109').text('Customer : XYZ - US');
}
```

I posted bit of my actual page.
I tested this code in fiddle It is working, but the same code in my application not working.

In browser page I am able to print the text "Customer : XYZ" in console by giving

```
$("#ui-dialog-title-detailsPopup_109").text()
```

I checked in Firebug, no errors/warning in page.

Comment: Have you made certain you dont have any duplicate id's?

Comment: If it's working in a fiddle it's something else in your site breaking before this code is run. Not enough information here to tell you what that is though.

Comment: it has at only one "ui-dialog-title-detailsPopup_109" place in complete document

Comment: Yes, but i can not post all my code - you might know , that makes problems. Please give some possible ways to solve this issue.

Comment: Try debugging. I'll start by `alert($('#ui-dialog-title-detailsPopup_109').length)` then trying to change its color e.g. `$('#ui-dialog-title-detailsPopup_109').css("color", "red");` - what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was overwriting by another function call. that i know but my unexpected thing is, that calls before my new function setPopupTitle,

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ui-dialog-title-detailsPopup_109').html('Customer : XYZ - US');
```

try this

Comment: sorry, not working, i put break points also even not debugging.

Comment: $(".ui-dialog-title").html('Customer : XYZ - US'); try this